# Problem with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to find local extrema of $f(x,y,z)=ax+by$ ($a,b$ non-zero and fixed) defined on $\{(x,y,z)\colon (x,y)\neq 0\}$ subject to

$$\left (R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 - r^2 = 0.$$

(here $0<r<R$ are fixed). Okay, let us define the auxiliary function by:

$$F(x,y,z) = ax+by - \lambda \left( \left(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 - r^2 \right).$$

How to get rid of $\lambda$ from $F^\prime_x, F^\prime_y, F^\prime_z$? Can one please help me to find stationary points of $F$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we calculate $F_x'$, $F_y'$, and $F_z'$:

$$F_x'=a-\lambda\left(2\left(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\times\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)=a+\frac{2\lambda x\left(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$F_y'=b-\lambda\left(2\left(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\times\frac{-2y}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)=b+\frac{2\lambda y\left(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$F_z'=-2\lambda z$$

To make these equations nicer, let's define $u:=\frac{2\left(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Now, setting the derivatives to $0$, we have the following system of equations:
$$0=a+\lambda x u$$
$$0=b+\lambda y u$$
$$0=-2\lambda z$$

From the final equation, we have either $\lambda=0$ (in which case we have a solution if and only if we also have $a=b=0$ and so $f(x,y,z)=0$), or $z=0$. Since we have dealt with the former case, we'll assume from here that $z=0$.

Now multiplying the first equation by $y$, the second by $x$, and taking the difference, we get
$$0=ay+\lambda xyu-bx-\lambda xyu=ay-bx$$
so we have $y=\dfrac{b}{a}x$.

Finally, we can plug this into our constraint equation:
$$\begin{align}&0=\left (R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 - r^2
\\\implies&0=\left (R-\sqrt{x^2+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2x^2}\right)^2 - r^2
\\\implies&r^2=\left (R-|x|\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2}\right)^2
\\\implies&\pm r=R-|x|\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2}
\\\implies&|x|=\frac{R\pm r}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2}}
\\\implies&x=\frac{\pm R\pm r}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2}}
\end{align}$$
Since we have $y=\frac{b}{a}x$,

$$y=\frac{\pm R\pm r}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2}}$$

Hence the critcal points are

$$\frac{a(\pm R\pm r)}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2}}+\frac{b(\pm R\pm r)}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2}}$$

Note in this final expression if we choose signs for $R$ and $r$ in the $ax$ term, we need to choose the same signs in the $by$ term.

Comment: Thank you! How do we know that there are no saddle points here, though?

Comment: @HannesT. You are right, sorry, I haven't done that - I assumed that we were using a loose definition of local extrema meaning all critical points. I suppose in principle we can look at the Hessian matrix to try and determine which of these critical points are true local extrema, but evaluating those things looks pretty nasty.